# Convert Long number into Date in access vba

Tags: date, ms-access, vba

I am having a field which contains date in the form of number and need to convert into equivalent date for further operations such as checking between the date with other date variables.

For example : My long number variable is

```
Dim ndate as Long
ndate=20140901
```

I need to get this ndate as date variable such as  01/09/2014 (dd/mm/yyyy)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can give you the answer 
If the date is 20140901
then newdate will have 01/09/2014

```
  dim newdate as date
  newdate = CDate(Right(ndate, 2) & "/" & Mid(ndate, 5, 2) & "/" & Left(ndate, 4))
```

Comment: incorrect order, the right() should appear before the mid(). Otherwise cdate() will think that the month is the day and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

```
dim actualdate as date
actualdate = dateserial(ndate\10000, (ndate mod 10000)\100, ndate mod 1000000)
```

DateSerial takes the arguments year, month, day. The \ operator performs division discarding the remainder, and mod performs a division returning the remainder.

Comment: Can you break up the year, month and date equations into separate lines, and work out which causes the overflow? Sorry just omw out to get some food

Comment: mod 1000000 should be mod 100, you only want 2 digits for the day